# List of x y coordinates wont show up in saved file

Tags: python, file

I'm trying to write a file which contains three header names and a list of x y coordinate pairs.

```
tittel = ""
xn = ""
yn = ""
x = []
y = []
x_v = []
y_v = []

def verdier():
    global x, y, x_v, y_v
    x = input("Skriv inn x-koordinatene, with space between each point : ")
    y = input("Skriv inn y-koordinatene, with space between each point: ")
    x_v = x.split()
    y_v = y.split()
    x_v = [float(xv) for xv in x_v]
    y_v = [float(yv) for yv in y_v]
verdier()

def navn():
    global xn, yn, tittel
    xn = input("Hva skal x-aksen hete? ")
    yn = input("Og hva skal y-aksen hete? ")
    tittel = input("Hva ønsker du som tittel på din nye graf? ")
navn()

def dataliste():
    global x, y
    for x, y in zip(x, y):
        print(x, y)
dataliste()

datalisten = zip(x, y)

def skrivfil():
    global tittel, xn, yn, x, y
    filnavn = input("Skriv inn filnavn: ")
    try:
        fil = open(filnavn, "w")
        fil.write(tittel)
        fil.write("\n")
        fil.write(xn)
        fil.write("\n")
        fil.write(yn)
        fil.write("\n")
        fil.write(datalisten)
        fil.close()
    except:
        print("ERROR")
skrivfil()
```

So far I'm only getting a file I can open in notepad with the headers only (despite ERROR being printed, the file is in /downloads). I've tried separating x and y values but that only complicated it more.

Comment: Get rid of the `try...except` so that you can see the error then post the full traceback as part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Two comments on your file writing function:

1. You can use `with open(...) as f` to automatically close the file in case of an error.
2. You cannot write zip objects but you can iterate over the zip and write one by one.

This should do:

```
def skrivfil():
    filnavn = input("Skriv inn filnavn: ")
    with open(filnavn, "w+") as fil:
        fil.write(tittel)
        for x0, y0 in zip(x_v, y_v):
            fil.write("\n%f %f" % (x0, y0))
```